# Create a DLL from a .lib file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, dllexport

This question is based on the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9999861/blackbriar

Now I have the problem that everytime I want to use the dll a `System.EntryPointNotFoundException` occurs. The message of the exception says, that the entry point with the name of the function I tried to call, was not found in my dll.

Here is an example function that is located in the .h file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall LDL_Init(char* code)
...
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And I imported the function in C# like this:

```
[DllImport("C:\\Path\\To\\Dll\\Example.dll", EntryPoint="LDL_Init", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]

public static extern int LDL_Init( [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.Text.StringBuilder code );
```

Does someone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

**Next Try:**

I analyzed the generated dll with Dependency Walker and recognized that no function was exported. So I Wrote a wrapper-class. Here the new code examples:

In Library.h:

```
int LDL_Init(char* code);
```

In LibraryWrapper.h:

```
#pragma once

    class __declspec(dllexport) LibraryWrapper
    {
    public:
        static int __cdecl LDL_Init(char* code);
    };
```

In LibraryWrapper.cpp.

```
#include "Library.h"
#include "LibraryWrapper.h"

int LibraryWrapper::LDL_Init(char* code){
    return LDL_Init(code);
}
```

In Library.cs:

```
[DllImport("C:\\Path\\To\\Dll\\Example.dll")]
public static extern int LDL_Init( [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.Text.StringBuilder code );
```

Sadly I have the same result at the execution of the program: The good old `System.EntryPointNotFoundException`...

Here a screenshot of the result of Dependency Walker:
[image: Screenshot of Dependency walker]

And without undecorating C++ methods:
[image: Dependency walker screenshot without undecorating]

Comment: Beware of what you see in Dependency Walker.  Note how it displays the full C++ declaration, even the class name is visible.  That is not actually how the function is exported, Depends could do this because it knows how to reverse the C++ mangled name.  The undname.exe utility is another one that knows how to do this.  So EntryPoint is not correct and `extern "C"` did not actually get the job done (a class can't be C), you have to apply it to the function instead.  Or use the Dumpbin.exe /exports or the linker's .map file to see the mangled name and fix the EntryPoint.

Comment: Another problem you have to fix is that the C++ function can't be a member function of the class.  Pinvoke can't do anything to create the C++ object and get it destructed again.  Use the `static` keyword.  If using a C++ member function is a hard requirement then you need to write a wrapper with C++/CLI

Comment: Where did `LdlWrapper` come from? If your wanting to export C++ classes to C# now and not the plain C functions then that is another layer of complexity.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the information of the Depnedency Walker and the mistakes in the code. I added static and deleted the extern "C".

Comment: @FireLancer LdlWrapper was wrong. Corrected it to LibraryWrapper. Sorry for that. The class LibraryWrapper is just to wrap the code that I actually want to export to C#

Comment: So problem solved?  Be sure to add your own post to explain what you did to solve the problem and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @HansPassant I added `EntryPoint="?LDL_Init@LibraryWrapper@@SAHPEAD@Z"` to the `DllImport` in the C#-Code. No exception occurs. But now when I call the function and pause the debugger, I see that Visual Studio is hanging there forever without doing anything. But I guess that is not the same problem as the initial one of this post. Or did someone have the same problem?

Comment: Right, not the same problem.  Just debug it.  Enable unmanaged debugging with Project > Properties > Debug tab and set a breakpoint on the C++ function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" the problem with the following adjustment in the file Library.cs:

```
[DllImport("C:\\Path\\To\\Dll\\Example.dll", EntryPoint="?LDL_Init@LibraryWrapper@@SAHPEAD@Z")]
public static extern int LDL_Init( [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.Text.StringBuilder code );
```

The string EntryPoint is based on the function name that Dependency Walker extracted from my dll. Afterwards I had the problem, that the execution of the code stood still at the line

```
return LDL_init(code);
```

In the file LibraryWrapper.cpp. Found this out by enabling "native code debugging" and pressing pause while debugging.

In the meantime I found a .dll that was provided by the producer of the device I want to control. I analyzed the .dll with Dependency Walker and inserted the EntryPoints. Now it works. Thanks for all the support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Microsoft [`DUMPBIN.EXE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=vs-2017) tool to check exports:

```
> dumpbin /EXPORTS Example.dll
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.14.26433.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file Example.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for Example.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           2 number of functions
           2 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          2    0 000110C3 LDL_Init = @ILT+190(LDL_Init)
          1    1 00011087 foo = @ILT+130(foo)

  Summary

        1000 .00cfg
        1000 .data
        1000 .idata
        2000 .pdata
        3000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
        8000 .text
       10000 .textbss
```

Any special things for the linker, such as `__declspec(dllexport)` or `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` need to be seen by the compiler or otherwise it will have no clue about them and neither will the linker. For modified header files this would mean including them at least once.

Alternatively for a module definition file (`.def`) it would need adding to the project (or adding the `/DEF filename` command line argument manually).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I achieved a next step, but could still not execute the program.

Comment: Not sure why you added a C++ class to the question. I am thinking the definition file is very much easier, it just needs a list of the function names you want and doesn't need extra source or messing with 3rd party lib files.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, use __cdecl.

__stdcall will add @parameter_bytes after the function name.